# Java Sudoku Squares 3x3 Checking Validity

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a Java program that checks if a sudoku puzzle is solved or not. I have finished the horizontal and vertical number check part. But when trying to check squares, I can't do anything. Here is how my check system works.

This is what I want to make. Hope someone helps because I'm on a hard situation with square check.

```
int[][] SudokuBoard = new int[9][9];
// I didn't wrote the sudoku board completely hope you understood how sudoku table looks like.

public static boolean checkSquares(int[][] SquareBoard) {
    int retr = false;
    int loop = 0;
    int[] extraboard = new int[9];
    int[] truelist ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for(int i = 1; i <=9 ; I++) {
        //here , extraboard will have the numbers in " i " numbered sudoku square.( i is like first //,second)
        Arrays.sort(extraboard);
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if(extraboard[j] == truelist[j])
                loop += 1;
        }
        extraboard = new int[9];
    }

    if(loop == 81)
        retr == true;

    return retr;
}
```

Comment: can you wait a minute I'm editing the code

Comment: how many squares there is in 3x3 sudoku? 4?

Comment: Ok well ignoring for a moment that this obviously doesn't compile, the idea to take a row/column/3x3-square and sorting it is pretty good. That's not how I'd do it myself, but it ought to work. You're just missing some details.

Comment: no, i wanted to say it's a normal sudoku board 9x9, and every square is 3x3 as in every sudoku in Turkish, Normal sudoku 9 tane 3x3 kare olur içindeki sayılar da 1-9 arası olur ya.

Comment: Why does your title says 3x3, but your double array is 9x9?

Comment: Because every square is 3x3 in sudoku not the big one.The small ones.

Comment: One thing, is this meant to check all the squares or just a single square? Checking for loop == 9 suggests you are only checking 1 line/square/row. Shouldn't the check be 81 if you are checking it for all squares?

Comment: Loop is increasing 1 if a 3x3 sub-square has right numbers so 9 sub-squares makes loop=9

Comment: You are still doing the command `loop += 1` 81 times with the 2 loops given that the sudoku is solved. (9 times inside each of the outer loops which are run 9 times = 81)

Comment: Ow sorry, i didnt understood it first because i deleted secondloop integer so now i'm editing.And hope you will help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
int count = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            extraboard[count++] = SquareBoard[i+3*k/3][j+k%3*3];
        }    
    }
    Arrays.sort(extraboard);
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if(extraboard[j] == truelist[j])
            loop += 1;
    }
    extraboard = new int[9];
    count = 0;
}
```

The actual formula to calculate the location in the box is quite simple. As the board is split into rows and column, getting the location of the row and column needs to get offset based on the location of the box in the full area.

i here counts the index within the box of the row. As each row of boxes has a length of 3 in a 9x9 sudoku we need to increase the row number by 3 each time we get 3 boxes in. To figure out and only add 3 we can use some integer division.

For example:

```
i+i.length*k/i.length
```

This is obviously an syntax error as i doesn't have length but can consider it as the limit of i in the loop (in this case 3).

This would then get the current row in the box (the first i) and add that to the offset of boxes in the sudoki. That is for every 3 boxes k/i.length becomes 1 more, and we then multiply that with 3 to get the offset of 3.

In the column part we have a bit of an bigger issue as we need to offset it for every 3 we move left in the array and reset it when we get back to boxes on the far left.

So the forumla would become

```
j + (k%i.length)*j.length
```

This would give us the column in the box we are in, then we offset by the box location with k%i.length. The reason we use the i.length and not the j.length is that we need to calculate the offset by rows and then offset it by the length of the box column wise.

With this you can then apply to this to any size board. 2x2, 2x3, 3x2, 3x3 or bigger even.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkSquares(int[][] SquareBoard) {
    int i=0, extraboard=0;
    for (;i<9;i++,extraboard=0) {
       for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
           extraboard+=1<<(SquareBoard[i/3*3+j/3][i%3*3+j%3]-1);
       if (extraboard!=(1<<9)-1) // 511, binary(511) = 111111111
           break;
    }
    return i==9;
}
```

Comment: Yes it says i is not initialized

Comment: I fixed initialized i = 0 and extraboard=0. it was an edit after I copied here.

Comment: I just compiled it no syntax errors. last confirmation please

Comment: Code is working but it doesn't give the true result.It says sudoku is not solved.But sudoku is solved.I think there is a little mistake with a number

Comment: Yes ı was right, you returned i == 9 but i returns 8 because itsnot '<=' operator.It's '<' operator.

Comment: ok fair enough thank you. I will delete the solution. but can you paste this test case here.

Comment: No problem, i thank you a lot because you teach me some usages of `<<` operator.

Comment: I need that test case please

Comment: Did you mean all of code ? Because i'm poor a bit at english

Comment: I mean the sudoku board you tested and gave wrong result.

Comment: i said that the return is wrong.Return should be  `return i == 8` because for loop works if i is less than 9 not is equal or less.I changed it and it works

Comment: no man. if i reached 9 that means it didn't break; and loop finished because of the loop conditions means sudoku is true. otherwise if i!=9 loop end because of if (extraboard!=123456789) which mean bad sudoku board.

Comment: if loop ends normally i must equal to 9 (i==9)

Comment: Okay than `static int SudokuTableSolved[][] ={
   {1,9,8,5,2,6,3,4,7},
   {7,2,5,3,4,1,6,9,8},
        {3,4,6,9,7,8,2,1,5},
        {9,8,1,2,5,7,4,6,3},
        {5,6,4,1,3,9,8,7,2},
        {2,3,7,6,8,4,1,5,9},
        {4,7,3,8,1,5,9,2,6},
        {8,1,9,7,6,2,5,3,4},
        {6,5,2,4,9,3,7,8,1},
     };`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution i came up with. it uses 4 nested loops but the time complexity is still O(n^2). Basically i check the first 3 boxes on top, then the 3 boxes in the middle, then the last 3 boxes.

```
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l+= 3){
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3){
                HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
                for (int j = l; j < l+3; j++){
                    for (int k = i; k < i+3; k++){
                        if (!set.contains(board[j][k])){
                            if (board[j][k] != '.')
                                set.add(board[j][k]);
                        }
                        else 
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
```

and note that the sudoku might not be complete, and the missing numbers are replaced by ' . '